# Schrodinger ParametricNDSolve doesn't plot anything

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I've been trying to plot the eigenfunctions of a square well with a quadratic surface. I don't know why, but when I try to plot it, it doesn't plot anything. Here is my code:

```
schrod = ParametricNDSolve[{-1/2 \[Psi]''[r] + r^2 == Ei \[Psi][r], \[Psi][-20] == 0, \[Psi][20] == 0}, 
         \[Psi][r], {r, -20, 20}, {Ei}];
Plot[\[Psi][5][r] /. schrod, {r, -20, 20}]
```

That's my code trying to plot the 5th eigenfunction, and this is what's returned.
[image: plot of the 5th eigenfunction]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the function to `ψ[r][5]`

```
Clear[schrod]; schrod = 
 ParametricNDSolve[{-1/2 ψ''[r] + r^2 == 
    Ei ψ[r], ψ[-20] == 0, ψ[20] == 0}, ψ[
   r], {r, -20, 20}, {Ei}];
Plot[ψ[r][5] /. schrod, {r, -20, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much!

Comment: @MichaelAdrianJavier  We can accept the answer by the symbol ✔  at the leftside of the answer.